# Find if object key is in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array of ids, consider the following

```
let ids = [1,2,3]
```

then an object, consider the following

```
let obj = {1:true, 2:true, 100:true}
```

how can i find if the object key is in the array, because the structure is weird it doesn't come with something you usually see like

```
let obj = { id: 1, value:true}
```

it just has the key as the id and the value as the right side of the key value

Comment: *"how can i find if the object key is in the array"*. What's the *"object key"* ?

Comment: _"how can i find if the object key is in the array"_ `ids.includes(object key)`

Comment: do you want only the first one?

Comment: **Which** of the object keys do you want to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All found `id` and mapping with an object.

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3],
    obj = { 1: true, 2: true, 100: true },
    result = ids
        .filter(k => k in obj)
        .map(id => ({ id, value: obj[id] }));

console.log(result);
```

A first found result

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3],
    obj = { 1: true, 2: true, 100: true },
    result = (id => ({ id, value: obj[id] }))(ids.find(k => k in obj));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ids = [1,2,3]

let obj = {1:true, 2:true, 100:true}

// test if the object has at least one key that is listed in [ids]
console.log(Object.keys(obj).some(x => ids.includes(Number(x)))); // true

// get the object keys that exist in [ids] and convert them to numbers
console.log(Object.keys(obj).filter(x => ids.includes(Number(x))).map(x=>Number(x))); // [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let ids = [1,2,3];
let obj = {1:true, 2:true, 100:true};

let result = Object.keys(obj).filter(id => {
    if(ids.indexOf(Number(id))>-1){return true}
})
```

**result** is an array with matched ids.